# Using Common Table Expressions for multi-time windows

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have run this query in SQL Server as:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT AIP.aid [Author_ID], 
           MIN(CAST(P.abstract_research_area as VARCHAR(100))) [Research_Area], 
           CAST(RC.research_category as VARCHAR(100)) [Research_Category], 
           P.abstract_research_area_category_id [Category_ID],
           COUNT(*) [Paper_Count], 
           P.p_year [Paper_Year]
    FROM author_individual_papers AIP
    JOIN sub_aminer_paper P ON AIP.pid = P.pid
    JOIN research_categories RC ON P.abstract_research_area_category_id = RC.category_id
    WHERE P.abstract_research_area_category_id IS NOT NULL AND
          AIP.aid IN (SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors) AND AIP.p_year BETWEEN 2005 AND 2014
    GROUP BY AIP.aid, 
             CAST(RC.research_category as VARCHAR(100)),
             P.abstract_research_area_category_id,
             P.p_year
),
CTE_1 AS 

(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(
            PARTITION BY Author_ID, Paper_Year 
            ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC, Research_Area ASC
        ) AS Rank
    FROM CTE 
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE_1
WHERE Rank <= 3
```

which returns this output:

```
+-----------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+------+    
| Author_ID | Research_Area          | Research_Category | Category_ID | Paper_Count | Paper_Year | Rank |  
+-----------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+------+
| 677       | feature extraction     | Data Mining       | 8           | 1           | 2005       | 1    |
| 677       | image annotation       | Image Processing  | 11          | 1           | 2005       | 2    |
| 677       | retrieval model        | Info retrieval    | 12          | 1           | 2005       | 3    |
| 677       | semantic               | Prog Languages    | 19          | 1           | 2007       | 1    |
| 677       | feature extraction     | Data Mining       | 8           | 1           | 2009       | 1    |
| 677       | image annotation       | Image Processing  | 11          | 1           | 2011       | 1    |
| 677       | semantic               | Prog Languages    | 19          | 1           | 2012       | 1    |
| 677       | video sequence         | Computation Math  | 5           | 2           | 2013       | 1    |
| 1359      | adversary model        | Analysis of Algo  | 1           | 2           | 2005       | 1    |
| 1359      | ensemble method        | Machine Learning  | 14          | 2           | 2005       | 2    |
| 1359      | image representation   | Image Processing  | 11          | 2           | 2005       | 3    |
| 1359      | adversary model        | Analysis of Algo  | 1           | 7           | 2006       | 1    |
| 1359      | concurrency control    | Signal Processing | 17          | 5           | 2006       | 2    |
| 1359      | information system     | Info retrieval    | 12          | 2           | 2006       | 3    |
| 1359      | algorithm analysis     | Analysis of Algo  | 1           | 3           | 2007       | 1    |
| 1359      | markov model           | Prob & Statistics | 18          | 2           | 2007       | 2    |
| 1359      | real time systems      | Signal Processing | 17          | 2           | 2007       | 3    |  
| 1359      | point based model      | Computation Math  | 5           | 3           | 2008       | 1    |
| 1359      | discriminant analysis  | Analysis of Algo  | 1           | 2           | 2008       | 2    |
| 1359      | fuzzy logic systems    | Artif Intelligence| 2           | 2           | 2008       | 3    |  
| ...       | ...                    | ...               | ...         | ...         | ...        | ...  |
| ...       | ...                    | ...               | ...         | ...         | ...        | ...  |
| ...       | ...                    | ...               | ...         | ...         | ...        | ...  |
+-----------+------------------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+------------+------+
```

This is showing TOP 3 ROWS for each `Author_ID` in every `Paper_Year` ranging BETWEEN `2005` to `2014` which is `ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC`. So now each `Author_ID` if having papers in each (10) `Paper_Year`, then will correspond to  `30` rows.

I want to display TOP 3 ROWS for each `Author_ID` not for every `Paper_Year` individually but for each `Paper_Interval` e.g. for `Paper_Interval` i.e. `2005-06`, `2007-08`, `2009-10`, `2011-12`, `2013-14`.

**The desired/expected* OUTPUT is:**
* If there is no paper in respected year for any author, in-spite of this, the year should get mentioned in the `Interval` e.g. `Author_ID = 677` has no paper in 2006, so still the `Interval` should get displayed as `2005-2006`.

```
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------+    
| Author_ID | Research_Category   | Category_ID | Paper_Count | Paper_Interval | Rank |  
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------+
| 677       | Data Mining         | 8           | 1           | 2005-06        | 1    |
| 677       | Image Processing    | 11          | 1           | 2005-06        | 2    |
| 677       | Info retrieval      | 12          | 1           | 2005-06        | 3    |
| 677       | Prog Languages      | 19          | 1           | 2007-08        | 1    |
| 677       | Data Mining         | 8           | 1           | 2009-10        | 1    |
| 677       | Image Processing    | 11          | 1           | 2011-12        | 1    |
| 677       | Prog Languages      | 19          | 1           | 2011-12        | 2    |
| 677       | Computation Math    | 5           | 2           | 2013-14        | 1    |
| 1359      | Analysis of Algo    | 1           | 9           | 2005-06        | 1    |
| 1359      | Signal Processing   | 17          | 5           | 2005-06        | 2    |
| 1359      | Machine Learning    | 14          | 2           | 2005-06        | 3    |
| 1359      | Analysis of Algo    | 1           | 5           | 2007-08        | 1    |
| 1359      | Prob & Statistics   | 5           | 3           | 2007-08        | 2    |
| 1359      | Artif Intelligence  | 2           | 2           | 2007-08        | 3    |  
| ...       | ...                 | ...         | ...         | ...            | ...  |
| ...       | ...                 | ...         | ...         | ...            | ...  |
| ...       | ...                 | ...         | ...         | ...            | ...  |
+-----------+---------------------+-------------+-------------+----------------+------+
```

whereas if I make `2` years interval for each `Author_ID` then each author will have `15` rows max if having papers in each `Paper_Interval` (5 Intervals).

Moreover, `Research_Category` with the *first highest total* `Paper_Count` in a single `Paper_Interval` will come at `Rank = 1` and vice versa. If there is a match in `Paper_Count` as in this case:

For `Author_ID = 1359` and `Paper_Interval = 2005-06`
In terms of *highest total* `Paper_Count`,

- *First Highest Total*    `Paper_Count = 9` for `Category_ID = 1`  will be at `Rank = 1`
- *Second Highest Total*   `Paper_Count = 5` for `Category_ID = 17` will be at `Rank = 2`
- *Third Highest Total*

There is a match in terms of *Third Highest Total* `Paper_Count` i.e.

```
Research_Area        | Category_ID | Paper_Count | Paper_Interval
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ensemble method      | 14          | 2           | 2005-06
image representation | 11          | 2           | 2005-06
information system   | 12          | 2           | 2005-06
```

Now, in this case we will choose *alphabetically* (`Research_Area`) for `Rank = 3` which comes `Category_ID = 14`.

**The question is**: how can we modify this query to get output in desired form for 5 intervals (i.e. `Paper_Interval`) for each `Author_ID`?

**ADDENDUM**
I have added 3 tables (used in the query) with sample data in `.csv` format in under-mentioned links as:
**CREATE TABLE author_individual_papers**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[author_individual_papers](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [aid] [int] NULL,
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [p_year] [int] NULL,
    [p_venue_vid] [int] NULL
)
```

Table link with sample data (only for `Author_ID` 677 & 1359)
[author_individual_papers](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ihKgOLimL0czV2cS1TZW10VWs/view?usp=sharing)

**CREATE TABLE sub_aminer_paper**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sub_aminer_paper](

    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [p_year] [int] NULL,
    [abstract_research_area] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [abstract_research_area_category_id] [int] NULL
)
```

Table link with sample data (only for `Author_ID` 677 & 1359)
[sub_aminer_paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ihKgOLimL0NXM4a0ppbEpJSHc/view?usp=sharing)

**CREATE TABLE research_categories**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[research_categories](
    [category_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [research_category] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

Table link with data
[research_categories](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6ihKgOLimL0WVdkakJFQlgxNTA/view?usp=sharing)

The desired/expected result is already mentioned above in the question.

Comment: don't quite understand what you mean by `5 windows`. Can you include the expected result in the question ?

Comment: Best was to include sample data and expected result corresponding to the given sample, thx

Comment: @Squirrel I have added sample output i.e. the expected result in the question.

Comment: @Shnugo I have added the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hopefully i got your requirement right.

```
DECLARE @year_start INT
DECLARE @year_end INT

SET @year_start = 2005
SET @year_end   = 2014
    ; WITH 
    CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  
            AIP.aid [Author_ID], 
            MIN(CAST(P.abstract_research_area as VARCHAR(100))) [Research_Area], 
            CAST(RC.research_category as VARCHAR(100)) [Research_Category], 
            P.abstract_research_area_category_id [Category_ID],
            COUNT(*) [Paper_Count], 
            --P.p_year [Paper_Year],                        -- removed
            (p.p_year - @year_start + 2) / 2 [Interval_No], -- added
            CAST(MIN(P.p_year) as VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(MAX(P.p_year) as VARCHAR(4)) [Interval] -- added
        FROM    
            author_individual_papers AIP
        JOIN    
            sub_aminer_paper P      
        ON  AIP.pid                 = P.pid
        JOIN    research_categories RC      
        ON  P.abstract_research_area_category_id    = RC.category_id
        WHERE   
            P.abstract_research_area_category_id    IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
            AIP.aid     IN (SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors) 
        AND 
            AIP.p_year  BETWEEN @year_start AND @year_end
        GROUP BY
            AIP.aid, 
            CAST(RC.research_category as VARCHAR(100)),
            P.abstract_research_area_category_id,
            --P.p_year,                        -- removed
            (p.p_year - @year_start + 2) / 2   -- added
    ),
    CTE_1 AS 
    (
        SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER(
                    PARTITION BY Author_ID, [Interval_No] -- changed
                    ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC, Research_Area ASC
                    ) AS Rank
        FROM    CTE
    )
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    CTE_1
    WHERE   Rank    <= 3
```

EDIT : Updated Query

```
DECLARE @year_start INT
DECLARE @year_end INT

SET @year_start = 2005
SET @year_end   = 2014

; WITH 
p_year AS   -- added
(
    SELECT  p_year  = @year_start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  p_year  = p_year + 1
    FROM    p_year 
    WHERE   p_year  < @year_end
),
Interval AS -- added
(
    SELECT  p_year, Interval_No, 
        Interval = CAST(MIN(p_year) OVER (PARTITION BY Interval_No) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + CAST(MAX(p_year) OVER (PARTITION BY Interval_No) AS VARCHAR(4))
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  p_year, (p_year - @year_start + 2) / 2 AS Interval_No
        FROM    p_year 
    ) AS D
),
CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
        AIP.aid [Author_ID], 
        MIN(CAST(P.abstract_research_area as VARCHAR(100))) [Research_Area], 
        CAST(RC.research_category as VARCHAR(100)) [Research_Category], 
        P.abstract_research_area_category_id [Category_ID],
        COUNT(*) [Paper_Count], 
        --P.p_year [Paper_Year],                        -- removed
        I.Interval_No,  -- added, changed
        I.Interval  -- added, changed
    FROM    
        author_individual_papers AIP
        JOIN    
        sub_aminer_paper P      
        ON  AIP.pid                 = P.pid
        JOIN    research_categories RC      
        ON  P.abstract_research_area_category_id    = RC.category_id
    JOIN    Interval I      -- added
    ON  P.p_year    = I.p_year
        WHERE   
        P.abstract_research_area_category_id    IS NOT NULL 
        AND 
            AIP.aid     IN (SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors) 
        AND 
        AIP.p_year  BETWEEN @year_start AND @year_end
        GROUP BY
        AIP.aid, 
        CAST(RC.research_category as VARCHAR(100)),
        P.abstract_research_area_category_id,
        --P.p_year,                        -- removed
        I.Interval_No, I.Interval   -- added, changed
),
CTE_1 AS 
(
    SELECT  *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER
        (
                    PARTITION BY Author_ID, [Interval_No] -- changed
                    ORDER BY Paper_Count DESC, Research_Area ASC
                ) AS Rank
        FROM    CTE
)
SELECT  * 
FROM    CTE_1
WHERE   Rank    <= 3
ORDER BY Author_ID, Interval, Rank
```

Comment: @Squirrel--The query executed without error now, but output is not as it was desired. I'll be back with elaborated results

Comment: i don't have the schema and sample to test to confirm. Please post the create table ... sample data and the expected result

Comment: @Squirrel--Now everything is here what you wanted but I just have added sample data for only two `Author_ID` i.e. 677 & 1359

Comment: @maliks. Updated the query

Comment: @Squirrel--Query is almost fine but it wasn't in the expected result that `Research_Category` picked up for `Author_ID=1359` for `Rank=3` is `Information Retrieval` with `Category_ID=12` whereas it should be `Machine Learning` with `Category_ID = 14` because here is match in _third highest total_ for `Paper_Count` so we'll choose alphabetically (`Research_Area`) which comes `ensemble method`. Also it is desired not to select `Research_Area` in the _result_ because its possible that there exist more than one `Research_Area` in single `Research_Category` so we'll select only `Research_Category`

Comment: @Squirrel--There are some issues with `Paper_Count` column as according to data, the subsequent values in `Paper_Count` column are not correct, that's why the `Rank` is disturbed and not right so as for `Interval_No = 2` for `Author_ID = 1359`

Comment: @Squirrel--will you please have a look back at this query?

Comment: @maliks , please verify the data in the `CTE` query. The `Rank` is based on result of the `CTE`

Comment: @Squirrel--I have given the current data and the result in desired form so how should I verify it more ?